# How to download a large file over HTTP in Camel without running out of memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, download, apache-camel

I am making a sort of api gateway using apache camel and spring boot to define routes to different services on our network. But I am having trouble with one route to a service which is used to download large (100mb ~ 500mb) files from our server. It seems that the file is always loaded completely into memory, coursing OutOfMemory exceptions if multiple people are calling it at the same time.

The route is defined as something like this:

```
restConfiguration()
    .component("undertow")
    .host("0.0.0.0")
    .port("{{api.port}}")
    .contextPath("/api");

rest("/download")
    .get("/{fileId}")
    .route()
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, constant("/download"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("fileid=${header.fileId}"))
    .toD("{{download-service.url}}?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

I have been trying to find a way to avoid it giving OutOfMemory exceptions when calling /download/, by trying out netty and jetty instead of undertow and enabling or disabling stream caching, but no matter what it keeps loading the entire file into memory instead of just sending it through to the client.

I hope one of you can help me with this.

Comment: What happens when you set parameter [disableStreamCache=true](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http-component.html#_query_parameters_38_parameters)?